# django sum of inline class price

Tags: django, aggregate

Here is the related App and Classes. Trying to get the sum of amount of all the components belonging to an invoice and save it in 'sub_total' field of Invoice. An invoice sub_total = sum of amount of all components of the invoice instance. What will be way around? Thanks in advance.

```
from stock.models import Part


class Invoice(models.Model): 
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)


class Component(models.Model):         
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice',)
    stock = models.ForeignKey('stock.Part',)
    qty =  models.SmallPositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2) 
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Show us your view and what have you done until this point ?? Where the error is coming. Don't expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: Was just hoping to get a clue, that is all. Something like this may not need views - done in models.py simply - that was I was hoping.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying things out, I finally got a clue and things are working fine now. I did not want complicated things in views or in the templates.

Below link has a fine example, and learnt from below and further testing seems to be working fine.

https://github.com/mwolff44/django-simple-invoice/blob/master/invoice/models.py
Around line number 194, something like below is shown, which tells us the clue as to what to do.

Below is similar to my "Invoice" Class
....

```
def total(self):
    total = Decimal('0.00')
    for item in self.items.all():
        total = total + item.total()
    return total
```

Then in Item (Component, in my case) Class. Around line number 281, something like below is shown. Although this has been taken care of earlier, thought others might find this useful.
...

```
def total(self):
    total = Decimal(str(self.unit_price * self.quantity))
    return total.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
```

Again, big thanks to Mathias WOLFF, https://github.com/mwolff44